# Same code different output between Pi3 and Pi4

Tags: pi-3, serial, pi-4

I got a simple rfid reader (brand unknown) connected to the serial0 rx port of a Pi4. Uploaden the following code and works perfect.

```py
class RFID():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/serial0",
                                baudrate = 9600,
                                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                                parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
                                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                                xonxoff=True

    def Read(self):
            while 1:
                received_data = None
                received_data = self.ser.read()
                time.sleep(0.03)
                data_left = self.ser.inWaiting()
                received_data += self.ser.read(data_left)
                self.received_data = received_data

     def returnTag(self):
            return self.received_data
```

The output is very neatly displayed with only giving an output after presenting the tag: `b'?\xe6\xa6f\xa6\xcc\x99\x97\x97ff\xa6)\xd6\xf2\x00`

Since the scanner eventually will be connected to a Pi3B I conducted the same steps strangely enough with with different result. The Pi3B is the flooding the terminal with `b\x00` if nothing is detected and if the tag is presented sometimes the correct but most of the time incorrect tag values.

To check if I maybe made a setting error, I conducted the steps at the same time with both a clean installed Buster on a Pi4 and a Pi3, again with the same result.

Anybody a clue what's happening?

Comment: Is Raspbian Buster fully updated - there were some serial bug fixes on the Pi4. sudo apt update, sudo apt full-upgrade

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick. Yes first thing I did before I continued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dun goofed myself... As the documention on the raspberryPi website states, the uart port the Rpi3 is shared with the bluetooth module.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

After disabling the bt module in the config file everything was working perfect. Nevertheless thanks.

Comment: The website says no such thing

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.